# wget link containing question mark

Tags: wget

I'm trying to download a .exe using the command line.

download link: `https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691980&clcid=0x409`

Doing `wget <link>` results in a file `index.html@LinkId=691980&clcid=0x409`

How do you deal with links that contain parameters at the end of the link? LinkId is necessary to download the correct .exe, so I can't just get rid of/ignore it.

Comment: wget takes a -O parameter to specify the name of the output file.

Comment: @jasonharper Yes but currently the file type is .html@Linketc... instead of .exe. It would just create an unexecutable file if I were to rename it as .exe

Comment: I just tried your link, and it isn't actually a download link - it's a web page, that loads another web page, that generates a binary blob for the browser to download.  If there is an actual URL for the executable file, you'd have to dig it out of the page JavaScript.  They seem to have gone to a considerable amount of trouble to keep people from downloading the file directly.

Comment: @jasonharper dang, well thank you!